# How to add context menu Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to create context menu in my project. On android it's called PopupMenu. On click of button, I have to show the popup with 3 rows and it's clickable event. How I can implement this in my code? Example of this menu here:

http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/popup2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Xamarin.Forms` way to handle this is to call `DisplayActionSheet()` on the Page.

It's not exactly a popup, but on the other hand it has better chances to be fully displayed and visible on screen if your view can scroll.

Comment: Thanks, it is my solution, you save my time